# How can I get a thumbnail depending on the extension of each ListView file?

Tags: c#, listview

I am using this to retrieve specific files from a USB thumb.

```
    public void leerArchivosUSB()
    {

        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("W:\\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(s => s.ToLower().EndsWith(".doc") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".docx") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".xls") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".xlsx") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".ppt") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".pptx") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg") || s.ToLower().EndsWith(".php"));

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(file);

        }

    }
```

But I would like either to set the icon on the listview depending on the extension, or making my own icons for each extension provided.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you're using winforms or WPF. If the latter, then I suggest you look at using a DataTemplate to define how the listbox items are displayed. You can use a TextBlock in the template for the file name and an Image for the icon. You would use a converter to get the icon from the file name.

On an iPad now, so can't post actual code, but do a search and you'll find plenty of examples of DataTemplates and converters. If you get stuck, update your question with your code, and we can help you fix it.